# Braintree implementation - getting the nonce payment on $_Post

Tags: javascript, php, braintree

I'm trying to test an implementation of Braintree with PHP and JS on a site. But unfortunately they have a very short tutorial on its website.

I would like to catch the 'payment_method_nonce' value from the payment form on to deal with that on my controller but the nonce insists in come empty.

There is a snippet of the code:

```
    <div class="braintree-form">
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin() ;?>
            <div id="payment-form"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
            </div>
        <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    </div>


<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var clientToken = <?php echo json_encode($clientToken); ?>;

    braintree.setup(
        clientToken,
        "dropin", {
            container: "payment-form",
            nonce: "fake-valid-nonce",
        }
    );
</script>
```

the configuration part:

```
Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('foo');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('bar');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('fxyzzy');
$clientToken = Braintree_ClientToken::generate();
```

when i try to read the value of `var_dump($_POST);` i get only

```
array (size=2)
  '_csrf' => string 'OXBEZ05MZW9cRHE0Kx9VCmoJFSAvFjYqVhoIVikWCSNJFjExBgE6PA==' (length=56)
  'payment_method_nonce' => string '' (length=0)
```

Shouldn't the attribute nonce on with the test value work on this way? I suppose i should receive on Post something saying that i got a valid nonce.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I work at Braintree. Are you receiving any JavaScript errors in the JavaScript console in your browser? I noticed that there are no quotes around the setting of `var clientToken`, which may be causing a problem. Additionally, the `json_encode` should not be necessary when setting a client token. Let me know if adding single quotes and removing `json_encode` resolve this issue.

Comment: Alessandro, did you ever overcome this issue? I'm having a similar one, with the [nonce coming back as an empty string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521105/braintree-dropin-form-issue-nonce-string-not-being-generated/33522928#33522928).