# Braintree dropin form issue - nonce string not being generated

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, forms, braintree

I'm trying to use the [dropin form](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v2#demo) from braintree but it produces a weird behaviour.

I can successfully place the form in a view:

```
<form id="createTransactionForm" method="post" action="#">
    <div id="payment-form"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Test - Pay">
</form>

<script>

    var braintreeToken = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.brainTreeToken));
    
    braintree.setup(
        braintreeToken,
        "dropin", {
            container: "payment-form"
        });

    ...
```

Here's the result:

[image: Braintree DropIn UI Form]

They state in their [documentation](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v2#send-payment-method-nonce-to-server) (3rd paragraph) that `braintree.js will add a hidden input named payment_method_nonce to your form`.

On my controller, I got the action method to catch the form collection and there's a `payment_method_nonce` key in the form collection with an empty string as a value but no other keys, no other form fields are caught here. I was expecting the card number and the expiration date, as seen in the picture above.

Using the inspector, I see that the braintree dropin cretes an HTML structure with nested forms:

[image: Nested forms]

My question is, how can I use the braintree dropin form and catch all their form input values in the action method?

## EDIT

OK, so thanks to @MikeMiller, I learned that I don't need to catch the CC values in the controller method, just the nonce string that's supposedly generated from them. However, I am getting an empty string.

From his suggestion, I tried to add to the form a specific value for the action attribute:

```
<form id="createTransactionForm" method="post" action="@Url.Action("MyMethod", "MyController")">
```

But the result is the same, an empty string for the nonce.

Comment: Yeah I have the issue with the null `payment_method_nonce`. You are not supposed to see any of the card details to process the payment server side all you need is the nonce value. This represents the payment method to Braintree so when you send this they pick up the credit card details or whatever were input in the drop in form.

Comment: Hmm, I'm using fake/test credit card values taken from [here](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm), maybe that's way the nonce returns as an empty string?

Comment: As long as the form validates the CC values as OK it shouldnt cause a problem. You are using the Sandbox app right?

Comment: I think we need to do more back and forth troubleshooting, and - given how much you and Mike Miller have already done on this question - I would recommend contacting [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com). When you do, include more samples of the server-side code you've got and, if possible, screenshots of the browser developer tools network view of the POST showing the empty value.

Answer (score 3):

I got mine working with the following code (Laravel5 blade). My issue was submitting the form with jQuery - without a button element in the form the nonce value doesnt get populated.

```
<form id="checkout" method="post" action="{{URL('admin/checkout')}}">
<div id="payment-form"></div>
<br>
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-btn" >
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" style="width:50px">
                <span data-bind="label" id="currency">&pound;</span>&nbsp;<span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="min-width:50px">
                <li style="width:50px"><a href="GBP">&pound;</a></li>
                <li style="width:50px"><a href="USD">&dollar;</a></li>
                <li style="width:50px"><a href="EUR">&euro;</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" class="form-control" />


    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button role="submit" class="btn  btn-primary btn-block" id="submit">Make Payment</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
<script>
  braintree.setup("@braintreeClientToken", "dropin", {
    container: "payment-form",
    form: 'checkout'
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Well, I'm assuming you tested it with real credit card values, did the nonce get populated then? And if you used the [test](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm) values, does it get populated?

Comment: I tested with valid CC details and a valid PayPal account. It doesnt matter if the CC are fake as long as the form passes validation and you can submit. If you click your submit button with empty fields in the form does it validate properly? ie turn the fields red and complain?

Comment: Yeah works fine with the test cards as well. I guess your issue is similar in that for some reason the JS that is supposed to fire when you click to submit your form isnt. If firing correctly it should validate your form, make an ajax call to retrieve the nonce and stick it in the hidden form field then submit the form as normal

Comment: The form validation works (turns fields red and complains if the values aren't valid) but the nonce never gets a value. When I click "submit", the form passes with an empty string for nonce. Why do you think this is?

Comment: Hmm I am not sure I am afraid. I can only assume it has something to do with how the form is being submitted but as far as I can tell there is nothing wrong with your HTML. Just for a pure experiment try to post it to a different URI (not to itself with the #) as this is the only difference I can spot between your code and the docos

Comment: Mike, edited my question. The result is the same, the nonce string is always empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94220/discussion-between-mike-miller-and-chiapa).

Comment: I may be able to add a little more insight into this problem.  Mike is correct you need a submit button and you need to allow it to use the action you specified.  This will allow the hidden braintree call to https://client-analytics.sandbox.braintreegateway.com to return and populate the nonce value before the form action is called.  Otherwise the hidden braintree call doesn't occur until after the action is called.  That is why your nonce value is empty.

Answer (score 1):

When you get an empty nonce, I was having the same trouble. However, in my case, I was doing 'custom' instead of 'dropin'. I did lots of tests in all kinds of scenarios, such as creating a static tokenization token from the dashboard, or generating one on the fly when the page loaded. They have some anti-fraud measures in place, I suspect, and it creates odd scenarios where the form submits no matter what, even if form validation routines fail. Or, the form submits and you get no nonce. The docs are also extremely confusing on this. So, this is the fix that I finally got going. [What they don't tell you in the docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/configuration) is that the `onPaymentMethodReceived` is only called on a form submit operation. The other remarkable discovery I made was that if I use the following code and add `<input type="hidden" name="payment_method_nonce" id="payment_method_nonce" />` to the form and then replace the `$('#token')` line below with a call to update the `payment_method_nonce` hidden field -- the Braintree API erases it right before form submit! So, the fix on that is to rename that hidden field to "token" and then on the form submit code in PHP I can process `$_POST['token']` instead of `$_POST['payment_method_nonce']`, but treat it like a nonce.

```
function invalidForm(){
    // use the Stripe or Braintree credit card form validator and any other form validations you want here
    // Braintree: https://github.com/braintree/card-validator
    // Stripe: https://github.com/stripe/jquery.payment
    // return a string value of the problem
    return '';
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    $('FORM#checkout').append('<input type="hidden" id="token" name="token" />');
    // Generate the static client token from your dashboard > Account > My User > 
    // Authorizations > Tokenization Keys
    var clientToken = 'sandbox_555555_555555555555';
    braintree.setup(clientToken, 'custom', {
        id:'checkout',
        onPaymentMethodReceived: function (paymentMethod) {
            $('#btnPurchase').addClass('disabled').attr('disabled');
            var sErr = invalidForm();
            if (sErr) {
                alert(sErr); // obviously do something better than this
                $('#btnPurchase').removeClass('disabled').removeAttr('disabled');
                return false;
            } // else...
            $('#token').val(paymentMethod.nonce);
            $('FORM#checkout').submit();
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```